# SQL query: Combining two tables to insert data in another one

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have these three tables and I want to insert a new event in a certain address but i don't know how to do that.

```
account(id, email, password)
address(id, city, street, number, c_id(foreign key for account))
event(id, title, description, e_id(foreign key for address))
```

The idea is an user can registry an event in his own address. Bellow what I'm trying to do.

```
/*I believe this can return multiple lines.*/
SELECT c_id FROM public.address WHERE city='new york';

/*This will return only one line.*/
SELECT id FROM public.account WHERE email='user01@gmail.com' AND password='user01';
```

The insertion in event would be something like:

```
/*I don't know how to combine those lines above.*/
INSERT INTO public.event(id, title, description, c_id, e_id) VALUES ('1', 'event title', 'event description', '????')
```

Comment: which DBMS? Most support an INSERT...SELECT combined syntax, or something similar. You should be able to merge your two select queries into one with an inner join (and so prevent it returning multiple rows for the address table, since it will just return the row matching the relevant user account - unless the user is allowed to register multiple addresses?).

Comment: I'm using PosgreSql. Still waiting for help.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-insert.html gives you the basic idea - see `INSERT INTO films SELECT * FROM tmp_films WHERE date_prod < '2004-05-07';`. Obviously you need to replace it with your fields, but it shows you can combine the insert and select operations into one. You also just need to combine your two select statements into one (this can be done using an inner join).

Answer (score -1):

In the address table you can make city a primary key,so that u can add it as a foreign key in event table.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Lots of addresses can exist within one city, so city can never (logically) be used as the primary key of that table. And even if it could, it has nothing to do with solving the problem. City is not required in the event table, since it can be derived by linking to the event table via address ID, which is already the primary key, and is already defined as the foreign key in the event table. OP's issue is how to combine the insert and select statements so they can use the existing selected keys in the insert query. Your suggestion is bizarre, to say the least.